# How to end this Proof in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I have managed to reduce my goal to

```
(fun x0 : PSR => me (x x0)) = x
```

I know that `reflexivity` will work, but for pedagogical reasons I prefer to continue reducing it.

`me` is an identity function so `unfold me` simplifies it to

```
(fun x0 : PSR => x x0) = x
```

which is just an anonymous function that applies the function `x` to a dummy variable `x0`, so you could say that both side are just the function `x`. If possible I would like to reach the same expression on both sides.

Comment: Coq has tactics for different reduction strategies, for example, `lazy`, `cbv`, `hnf`. You can also specify the kind of reduction you want to perform with some of these tactics, for example, `lazy delta` performs only δ-reduction, `lazy beta zeta` performs only βζ-reduction. You can't perform η- (eta-) reduction with these tactics though, probably because η-convertibility was added only recently to Coq's logic. You can however use the `change` tactic to change the conclusion of your goal (or a hypothesis) to any convertible conclusion (or hypothesis), `change (x = x)`.

Comment: Still very new to Coq, hell I am even sort of new to Haskell, but all this is very interesting! Unfortunately at the moment I don't understand very much about reductions.

Comment: Beta-reduction simplifies lambdas (`(λ x, y) z` to `y [x := z]`), zeta-reduction simplifies let-expressions, delta-reduction unfolds definitions, iota-reduction simplifies match patterns, eta-reduction simplifies `λ x, (f x)` to `f` (assuming `x` doesn't occur free in `f`). `lazy` evaluates lazily, `cbv` (call-by-value) evaluates eagerly (I think), `hnf` (head normal form) evaluates only on the left (the head). [Tactics](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactic-index.html).

Comment: Actually, the reason there's no eta-reduction, only eta-conversion, is because [it's not type safe](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#conv-rules).

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.
```

and then:

```
rewrite -> eta_expansion.
```

This uses the axiom of dependent functional extensionality though.